# pip rejects binaries when installing using requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip

Why does Python `pip` reject binaries when installing package from `requirements.txt`?
I am not using `--no-binary`, and I could not find any mention that this could be the default. It definitely is not when installing without `requirements.txt`.

When I install `django-silk` package in this way, it succeeds:

```
pip install -v django-silk==4.1.0
```

But when `django-silk==4.1.0` is in my `requirements.txt`, and I run this exact command line:

```
pip install -v -r requirements-prod.txt
```

I get the following log:

```
(...)
  Skipping link: No binaries permitted for django-silk: (...)
  Found link (...) version: 3.0.4
  Skipping link: No binaries permitted for django-silk: (...)
  Found link  (...) version: 4.0.0
  Skipping link: No binaries permitted for django-silk: https://files.pythonhosted.org/(...)/django_silk-4.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (...)
  Skipping link: No binaries permitted for django-silk: https://files.pythonhosted.org/(...)/django_silk-4.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (...)
  Skipping link: No binaries permitted for django-silk: https://files.pythonhosted.org/(...)/django_silk-4.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (...)
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'django-silk': discarding no candidates
(...)
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for django-silk==4.1.0
```

Why does `pip` decide that `No binaries permitted for django-silk`?

**Update:** It seems that the issue is not with `requirements.txt` file itself, but in the fact that `requirements.txt` also contains another package:

```
PyYAML --global-option="--with-libyaml" ; sys_platform != 'win32'
django-silk==4.1.0
```

So apparently the fact that `PyYAML` must be installed from source makes `pip` ignore binary packages for `django-silk` as well. Why does that happen?

> **Note:** I am using `Python 3.7.5` and `pip 21.0.1`.

Comment: Apparently it has no source distribution, just wheel.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't it install the wheel when "requirements.txt" is used, but does install it when "requirements.txt" is not used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out this is caused by a bug in `pip`:
"--global-option for a specific requirement in requirements file disables use of wheels globally"
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4118

Comment: Interesting. I think you can accept this answer.